# Trim number before decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="strong font-xs-12 font-sm-14 font-lg-16 red numTxt">£123.99</li>
```

I just want the value £123 to show, need correct Javascipt to "trim" the number and not round it down or up. I've seen a few ways on here but none that target .class name, in my case .numTxt

If somebody can do me a quick fiddle I would be most appreciative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.text()` call back function to modify the old text with new text:

```
$('li.numTxt').text(function(i,val){
    return  val.split(".")[0];
});
```

**### Working Demo**

Answer (score 2):

Just use this Regex `/\.\d+/`:

```js
$.fn.trimDecimal = function(){
  
  $(this).text(function(a, text){
     return text.replace(/\.\d+/,"")
  })
  
}

$(".numTxt").trimDecimal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="strong font-xs-12 font-sm-14 font-lg-16 red numTxt">£123.99</li>
<li class="strong font-xs-12 font-sm-14 font-lg-16 red numTxt">£83.45</li>
```

To truncate a decimal number, you can do it in this way:

```js
var num = "123.99";
num = +num | 0;

console.log(num)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
alert(document.querySelector('li').innerText.replace(/\.\d*/,''));
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with **[split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)**

```
var str = "£123.99"
var res = str.split(".");

//res is now an array consisting of "£123" and "99"
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var str = $('#inp').val();
    var res = str.split(".");
   
    $('#output').html(res[0]);
});
```

```css
input, button, div { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp" value="£123.99" />
<button>Split At Decimal</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```